# Shall programmer use "foreach var" instead "foreach AnyClass" in C#?

Tags: c#

Which code block is better?

```
            foreach (CloudBlockBlob b in allBlobs)
            {
                res.Add(b.Name);
            }
```

or

```
        foreach (var listBlobItem in allBlobs)
        {
            var b = (CloudBlockBlob) listBlobItem;
            res.Add(b.Name);
        }
```

I don't know why "foreach (var ...)" is more popular.

Comment: `var` is replaced with the class in compilation, so both are equal. `var` is more popular because is way more simple to type.

Comment: The only way this question would kind of make sense is if it turns out `allBlobs` is `object[]`, `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<object>` or some other moral equivalent (and is known to only actually contain `CloudBlockBlob` instances). Since you haven't shown us the definition of it though, impossible to say.

Comment: allblob ist List<IListblobItem>